# Make onTouch not pick up a scroll/swipe

Tags: android, button, touch, listener, ontouchlistener

My design consists of a `HorizontalScrollView` and a `LinearLayout` with a few `Button`s within it.

How can I make the `onTouch` handler of the `View.OnTouchListener` class, that's being set as the `onTouchListener` for the buttons, not pick up the action if it's not actually clicking the button, but scrolling about? Here's what I'm currently using:

```
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
```

I'm also measuring for how long the buttons are being held, so a click listener is also not an option.

Answer (score 0):

If an `OnClickListener` will not work for you, your current solution is your next best option.